# nginx strip "Set-Cookie" in frontend config on static files like jpg

Tags: php, cookies, nginx

I have a few questions about how do I configure it.

First question:

How do I strip the "Set-Cookie" header from all static files like css and jpg? I know i can setup a reverse proxy and use "proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie", but seems like foolish to make yet another host, just to reverse to your self and add a few hundred msec to the request.

Second question:

I'm trying to make an alias to hide a folder in the lookup to the subfolder, the structure is:

```
/var/www/domain.tld/media/ads
/var/www/domain.tld/media/galleries
/var/www/domain.tld/media/misc
/var/www/domain.tld/media/thumbs
```

making the url like this /media/thumbs/5 subfolders/image-file

how do i change that into /thumbs/5 subfolders/image-file

I have tried with both alias and root but both returns a 404

Third question:

```
[error] 9178#9178: *13452 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock", host:
```

have a lot of those, any suggestions?

nginx.conf

```
#user  nginx;
user    apache;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    aio threads;
    sendfile        on;
    sendfile_max_chunk  1m;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    server_tokens off;
    keepalive_timeout 15;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    client_body_buffer_size 10K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;
    index              index.php index.html index.htm;

    ## Nginx’s Open file cache https://easyengine.io/tutorials/nginx/open-file-cache/
    open_file_cache          max=5000 inactive=5m;  ##If you have way too many files, change max from 5000 to more appropriate value.
    open_file_cache_valid    20m;   ## Tell nginx to check if information it is holding is valid every n minutes.
    open_file_cache_min_uses 1;     ## If files don’t change much often, or accesses less frequently, you can change inactive duration from 20m to something else.
                                                                ## Inactive andopen_file_cache_min_uses works together.
                                                                ## This sample tells nginx to cache a file information as long as minimum 2 requests are made during 5m window.
    open_file_cache_errors   on;    ## Tell nginx to cache errors like 404 (file not found). If you are using nginx as load-balancer, leave this off.

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
        text/css
        text/javascript
        text/xml
        text/plain
        text/x-component
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/rss+xml
        application/atom+xml
        application/rdf+xml
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        font/truetype
        font/opentype
        image/svg+xml;

    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"; #Cross-site scripting
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always; #clickjacking
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff; #MIME-type sniffing

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

domain.tld.conf

```
server {
    listen       ip:80;
    listen          [ipv6]:80;
    server_name  domain.tld www.domain.tld;
        index  index.php =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        root   /var/www/domain.tld;
        expires                             max;
        add_header Pragma "public";

#include /etc/nginx/conf.d/mechbunny.inc;


    set $site_root $document_root;


    charset utf-8;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    location / {
        if ($arg_max) { expires max; }
        rewrite ^/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&page=$1;
        rewrite ^/galleries/(.*)-([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=gallery&id=$2;
        rewrite ^/video/(.*)-([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=video&id=$2;
        rewrite ^/signup$ /index.php?controller=signup;
        rewrite ^/upload$ /index.php?controller=upload;
        rewrite ^/upload_photo$ /index.php?controller=upload&option=photo;
        rewrite ^/login$ /index.php?controller=login;
        rewrite ^/logout$ /index.php?controller=logout;
        rewrite ^/contact$ /index.php?controller=contact;
        rewrite ^/forgot-pass$ /index.php?controller=forgot_pass;
        rewrite ^/my-profile$ /index.php?controller=my_profile;
        rewrite ^/my-friends$ /index.php?controller=my_friends;
        rewrite ^/my-friends/$ /index.php?controller=friends;
        rewrite ^/my-friends/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=friends&page=$1;
        rewrite ^/edit-profile$ /index.php?controller=edit_profile;
        rewrite ^/edit-content/(.*)$ /index.php?controller=editContent&id=$1;
        rewrite ^/static/(.*)$ /index.php?controller=displayStatic&id=$1;
        rewrite ^/load/(.*)$ /index.php?controller=loadLayout&id=$1;
        rewrite ^/filter/(.*)$ /index.php?controller=setFilter&id=$1;
        rewrite ^/embed/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?controller=embed&id=$1;
        rewrite ^/dmca$ /index.php?controller=dmca;
        rewrite ^/tos$ /index.php?controller=tos;
        rewrite ^/crss/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?controller=crss&id=$1;
        rewrite ^/rss$ /index.php?controller=rss;
        rewrite ^/a/(.*)$ /index.php?controller=link&slug=$1;
        rewrite ^/(my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1;
        rewrite ^/(my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
        rewrite ^/(my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends)/(day|week|month)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2;
        rewrite ^/(my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends)/(day|week|month)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&dateRange=$2&page=3;
        rewrite ^/(my-uploads|favorites|most-recent|most-discussed|most-viewed|longest|top-rated|photos|random|my-friends)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=$1&page=$2;
        rewrite ^/uploads-by-user/([0-9]+)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=uploads-by-user&user=$1;
        rewrite ^/uploads-by-user/([0-9]+)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=uploads-by-user&user=$1&page=$2;
        rewrite ^/search/(videos|members|photos)/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=search&type=$1&q=$2&page=1;
        rewrite ^/search/(videos|members|photos)/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=search&type=$1&q=$2&page=$3;
        rewrite ^/search/(videos|members|photos)/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/(newest|rating|views|longest)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=search&type=$1&q=$2&page=1&sortby=$3;
        rewrite ^/search/(videos|members|photos)/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/(newest|rating|views|longest)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=search&type=$1&q=$2&page=$4&sortby=$3;
        rewrite ^/search/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=search&q=$1&page=1;
        rewrite ^/search/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=search&q=$1&page=$2;
        rewrite ^/search/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/(newest|rating|views|longest)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=search&q=$1&page=1&sortby=$2;
        rewrite ^/search/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/(newest|rating|views|longest)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=search&q=$1&page=$3&sortby=$2;
        rewrite ^/channels/$ /index.php?controller=channels;
        rewrite ^/channels/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=channel&channel=$1;
        rewrite ^/channels/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/page(.*).html$ /index.php?mode=channel&channel=$1&page=$3;
        rewrite ^/channels/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/(newest|rating|views|longest)/$ /index.php?controller=index&mode=channel&channel=$1&sortby=$3;
        rewrite ^/channels/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/(newest|rating|views|longest)/page(.*).html$ /index.php?mode=channel&channel=$1&sortby=$2&page=$4;
        rewrite ^/models/$ /index.php?controller=pornstars;
        rewrite ^/models/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=pornstars&page=$1;
        rewrite ^/models/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/$ /index.php?controller=pornstars&letter=$1&page=1;
        rewrite ^/models/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=pornstars&letter=$1&page=$2;
        rewrite ^/models/(.*)-(.*).html$ /index.php?controller=pornstar_bio&id=$2;
        rewrite ^/stars/$ /index.php?controller=pornstars;
        rewrite ^/stars/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=pornstars&page=$1;
        rewrite ^/stars/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/$ /index.php?controller=pornstars&letter=$1&page=1;
        rewrite ^/stars/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=pornstars&letter=$1&page=$2;
        rewrite ^/stars/(.*)-(.*).html$ /index.php?controller=pornstar_bio&id=$2;
        rewrite ^/mailbox/$ /mailbox.php;
        rewrite ^/mailbox/([0-9]+)$ /mailbox.php?mode=inbox&page=$1;
        rewrite ^/mailbox/inbox/(.*)$ /mailbox.php?mode=inbox&page=$1;
        rewrite ^/mailbox/outbox/(.*)$ /mailbox.php?mode=outbox&page=$1;
        rewrite ^/mailbox/read/([0-9]+)$ /mailbox.php?mode=read&mid=$1;
        rewrite ^/mailbox/read/([0-9]+)/delete/$ /mailbox.php?mode=read&mid=$1&delete=true;
        rewrite ^/mailbox/read/([0-9]+)/spam/$ /mailbox.php?mode=read&mid=$1&spam=true;
        rewrite ^/mailbox/compose/(.*)/reply/$ /mailbox.php?mode=compose&mid=$1&reply=true;
        rewrite ^/mailbox/inbox/$ /mailbox.php?mode=inbox;
        rewrite ^/mailbox/outbox/$ /mailbox.php?mode=outbox;
        rewrite ^/mailbox/compose/$ /mailbox.php?mode=compose;
        rewrite ^/user/(.*)-(.*)/$ /index.php?controller=user_profile&id=$2;
        rewrite ^/members/$ /index.php?controller=members;
        rewrite ^/members/page([0-9]+).html$ /index.php?controller=members&page=$1;
             if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                #
                # Om nom nom cookies
                #
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                #
                # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
                #
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
                #
                # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
                #
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
             }
             if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
             }
             if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
             }
    }

        location /thumbs/ {
                alias /var/www/domain.tld/media/thumbs/;
        }

        location /admin/ {
                #index index.php;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found                   off;

        }

        location ~ \.mp4$ {
              limit_rate_after          5m;
              limit_rate                832k;
              mp4;
              mp4_buffer_size       1m;
              mp4_max_buffer_size   5m;
              gzip off;
              sendfile                          on;
              aio                                       on;
        }

        location ~ \.flv$ {
                flv;
                aio                                     on;
                limit_rate_after            10m;
              limit_rate                812k;
                sendfile                            on;
                }

    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
            access_log off;
            log_not_found                   off;
            aio                                     on;
            sendfile                            on;

            expires max;
            add_header                      Pragma 'public';
            add_header            X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

UPDATE ****

Here is a head fron one image

```
http://myvid.top/media/thumbs/5/6/f/b/7/56fb7cba222923.18247994.webm/56fb7cba222923.18247994.webm-1.jpg

GET /media/thumbs/5/6/f/b/7/56fb7cba222923.18247994.webm/56fb7cba222923.18247994.webm-1.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: myvid.top
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: da,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Referer: http://myvid.top/
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1355160255.1459328438; __utma=119888788.1355160255.1459328438.1459770326.1459782541.4; __utmz=119888788.1459782541.4.2.utmcsr=reck.dk|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/; __cfduid=daaae6531daf0d7dc53e01debcae7fcec1459759671; cookies_accepted=T; PHPSESSID=1jdr3p0r8e6i7kt5rmek0fru51; sidebar=open
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 06 Apr 2016 14:48:37 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 12416
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Apr 2016 19:49:49 GMT
Etag: "56fed0dd-3080"
Expires: Sat, 04 Apr 2026 14:48:37 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=315360000
Pragma: public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
cf-cache-status: EXPIRED
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: cloudflare-nginx
cf-ray: 28f60ab170193cef-CPH
```

and with
curl -LI http://myvid.top/media/thumbs/5/6/f/b/7/56fb7cba222923.18247994.webm/56fb7cba222923.18247994.webm-1.jpg

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 06 Apr 2016 14:53:35 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 12416
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=df383ea768b557dd9c4ddc40033b6bbf71459954415; expires=Thu, 06-Apr-17 14:53:35 GMT; path=/; domain=.myvid.top; HttpOnly
Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Apr 2016 19:49:49 GMT
ETag: "56fed0dd-3080"
Expires: Sat, 04 Apr 2026 14:53:35 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=315360000
Pragma: public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
CF-Cache-Status: MISS
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 28f611f6fae5105b-CDG
```

Comment: Who sends `Set-Cookie`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but as I can see it most be the webspript, because when I'm looking at the header, there's added a cookie to all static files like jpg

Comment: Here is a head fron one image

Comment: It's CloudFlare's cookie, so you cannot “unset” it in your nginx.

Comment: thx a lot Alexey Ten..... then I better understand why I can't see where they come from :)